# sum two textinput in flash and show in textfield?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I want to sum two text input and show result in text field.

I use flash and as2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any code to post showing effort?

Here are the things you should look at.

Validate text field 1 and 2 to ensure that only numbers are entered (look at "restrict").

Convert your text to numbers (look at "Number()" and perform the math (text3.text = num1 + num2 then output it to another text area.

Awww heck... Im in a good mood this morning

```
private function addFields():void{    
    text3.text = (Number(text1.text) + Number(text2.text)).toString();
}

<s:textInput id="text1" restrict"0-9"/>
<s:textInput id="text2" restrict"0-9"/>
<s:textInput id="text3"/>
```

Then just add a button with its onClick set to call addFields().

Next time, post some of the things you have tried and folks will generally be faster and more willing to help. Have a good one.

Comment: Hmmm... just saw that you wanted to do this in AS2. Ignore the s:textInput part. The rest SHOULD still hold true.